# Proving Big-Omega for $14n^3 = \Omega( 15n^3 + n + 19 )$

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, asymptotics

Suppose $f(n) = 14n^3$ and  $h(n) = 15n^3 + n + 19$.

How can I prove that $f(n) \in \Omega(h(n)) $ ?

Attempt:

$ f(n) \in \Omega(h(n)) $

$ f(n) \geq M*h(n) $

$ 14n^3 \geq M * (15n^3 + n + 19) $

$ 10n^3 + 4n^3 \geq 15Mn^3 + Mn + 19M  $

$ \Longrightarrow  10n^3 + 4n^3 \geq 15Mn^3 + Mn $

The last step above is where I'm unsure if it is allowed.

From here we can use the above equation and find M and n0 like:

### M

$ 10n^3 \geq 15Mn^3 $

$ 10/15 \geq M $

$ M = 10/15 $

### n_0

$ 4n^3 \geq Mn $

$ 4n^2 \geq M $

Sub in M

$ 4n^2 \geq \frac{10}{15} $

$ n >= \sqrt{\frac{10}{60}} $

$ n0 = \sqrt{\frac{10}{60}} $

Then a formal proof can be written from here.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! It looks like you used some MathJax here, but you want to use MathJax for *any* mathematical expression, including in the title. :)

Comment: Additionally you can use `\sqrt{x}` to denote $\sqrt{x}$ and `\leq` to denote $\leq$.

Comment: And `\geq` yields $\geq$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be honest I am a little confused by your steps. Your constants seem fine but you could have done it an easier way since you just need to show existence of **any** $n_0, M$

Choose $n_0=20$. Notice that if $n\geq n_0$ then $n^3 > n > 19$.

As such, if $n\geq 20$ then
$$
15n^3+n+19\leq 15n^3 + n^3 + n^3 = 17n^3.
$$

Choose $M=\frac{1}{10}$ (or really any value thats less than $\frac{15}{17}$). We know that $\forall n \geq 20$ that
$$
14n^3 > M\cdot 17n^3 = \frac{17}{10} n^3,
$$

therefore if $n \geq 20$ and $M = \frac{1}{10}$ then
$$
14n^3 \geq M\cdot 17n^3 \geq M\cdot\left(15n^3+n+19\right).
$$

As such $15n^3+n+19\in\Omega\left(14n^3\right)$. Q.E.D.